# Looping Srategies For Many Loops

Tags: java, loops

With looping strategies is 32 million too much for looping strategy digestion? Please inform me before deadline of tomorrow at 4. Thank you for assistance. I know syntax but struggles of conceputal.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do not abuse the caps lock button.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive; what are you doing in these loops?

Comment: The answer is that it depends what you are doing in / with the loop.

Comment: I MUST LOOP 32 MILLION DB RECORDS USING THE JAVA

Comment: THE DB IS ORACLE 9I. PLEASE STRESS LEVEL IS HIGH.

Comment: You are not giving much information for people to help you though. Try answering some of the comments..

Comment: Your stress levels and your deadlines are not our concern.  Please be professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32 million records is a large amount of almost anything, however if you are receiving the information from a Database perhaps there is a way to break it up into to parallel chunks.  You could devise a strategy to execute a series of queries and combine the results.  Take a look at the Java Future class which will let you compose a unit of work and then create a List of those units to be executed in parallel.

Comment: THESE ANSWER IS PERFECT FOR MY USE CASE. TANKS.

Comment: I like tanks. Tanks are great

Answer (score 0):

A program that makes 32 million database queries / updates / inserts / deletes in a loop from Java is not a good idea ... if you want to get the job done quickly and efficiently.

However, the fact remains that it depends on exactly what you are doing in the loop ... and other things, like whether you are doing this in a single transaction.

Depending on what it is you are trying to do, there are various techniques that can perform the task more efficiently; e.g. batching, bulk inserts, clever queries, and so on.  But we can't advise you without some details.